# TypeORM - PostgreSQL - Digital Ocean - MustBeEntityError

Tags: javascript, postgresql, digital-ocean, nestjs, typeorm

I'm faceing an issue with TypeOrm using type PostgreSQL connecting my database to Digital Ocean.
The connection works fine, entity is linked and generated but when i'm trying to make a **POST** request on **localhost/users**, i get **MustBeEntityError: Cannot save, given value must be an entity, instead "undefined" is given** while **GET** works like a charm and returns the data

user.entity.ts

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Unique } from "typeorm";

@Entity({
  name: 'user',
})

export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;
}
```

user.repository.ts

```
import {EntityRepository, Repository} from "typeorm";
import { UserEntity } from "./user.entity";

@EntityRepository(UserEntity)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<UserEntity> {

  async findAllUsers(){
    return await this.find()
  }

  async createUser(userAccount: UserEntity){
      return await this.save(userAccount)
  }
}
```

user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserRepository } from "./user.repository";
import { UserEntity } from "./user.entity";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}
  async find() {
    return await this.userRepository.findAllUsers()
  }
  async create(user: UserEntity) {
    return await this.userRepository.createUser(user)
  }
}
```

user.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Get, Post } from "@nestjs/common";
import { UserService } from "./user.service";

@Controller('users')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {
  }
  @Get()
  async findAll(){
    return await this.userService.find()
  }
  @Post()
  async create(user){
    return await this.userService.create(user)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I completely forgot about @Body decorator, it solved my issue